# Dragging a rotated element within a certain boundary

Tags: javascript, raphael

In the following fiddle, you can click and drag around the image, and it will not be able to exit the blue border.  By clicking the red and green rectangles, you can rotate the image.  However when you click and drag a rotated object, the image does not follow the mouse.  I would like the image to follow the mouse even if it is rotated.

http://jsfiddle.net/n3Sn5/

I think the issue occurs within my move function

```
move = function (dx, dy)
{
  nowX = Math.min(boundary.attr("x")+boundary.attr("width")-this.attr("width"), this.ox + dx);
  nowY = Math.min(boundary.attr("y")+boundary.attr("height")-this.attr("height"), this.oy + dy);
  nowX = Math.max(boundary.attr("x"), nowX);
  nowY = Math.max(boundary.attr("y"), nowY);

  this.attr({x: nowX, y: nowY });
}
```

One thing to notice is that when you click and drag a rotated object, after you release your mouse click, if you rotate the image, it snaps to where your mouse was when you released the mouse click, even obeying the boundary.

I was able to get the rotated image to drag with the mouse previously, but by adding the boundary rectangle, i had to use a more complex approach.

If anyone has an idea of what I need to change, I would be very grateful!
Thanks!

Comment: I have come across Free Transform, a plugin for Raphael JS, which has boundary locking capabilities built in.  Anyone who is interested: http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required output can be achieved in a bit different way. Please check the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/6BbRL/. I have trimmed to code to keep the basic parts for demo.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 475, 475),
    boxX = 100,
    boxY = 100,
    boxWidth = 300,
    boxHeight = 200,
    // EDITED
    imgWidth = 50,
    imgHeight = 50,

    box = paper.rect(boxX, boxY, boxWidth, boxHeight).attr({fill:"#ffffff"}),
    // EDITED
    html5 = paper.image("http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_512.png",boxX+boxWidth-imgWidth,boxY+boxHeight-imgHeight,imgWidth,imgHeight)
        .attr({cursor: "move"}),

    elementCounterClockwise = paper.rect(180, 0, 50, 50).attr({fill:"#ff5555", cursor:"pointer"}),
    elementClockwise = paper.rect(250, 0, 50, 50).attr({ fill: "#55ff55", cursor: "pointer" }),

    boundary = paper.rect(50,50,400,300).attr({stroke: '#3333FF'}),

    transform,
    // EDITED
    xBound = {min: 50 + imgWidth/2, max: 450 - imgWidth/2},
    yBound = {min: 50 + imgHeight/2, max: 350 - imgHeight/2};

start = function (x, y) {
    // Find min and max values of dx and dy for "html5" element and store them for validating dx and dy in move()
    // This is required to impose a rectagular bound on drag movement of "html5" element.
    transform = html5.transform();
}

move = function (dx, dy, x, y) {
    // To restrict movement of the dragged element, Validate dx and dy before applying below.
    // Here, dx and dy are shifts along x and y axes, with respect to drag start position.
    // EDITED 
    var deltaX = x > xBound.max && xBound.max - x || x < xBound.min && xBound.min - x || 0;
        deltaY = y > yBound.max && yBound.max - y || y < yBound.min && yBound.min - y || 0;
    this.attr({transform: transform + 'T'+ [dx + deltaX, dy + deltaY]});     
}

up = function () {
};

html5.drag(move, start, up);

elementClockwise.click(function() {
  html5.animate({transform: '...r90'}, 100);
})

elementCounterClockwise.click(function() {
  html5.animate({transform: '...r-90'}, 100);
})
```

Use of '...' to append a transformation to the pre-existing transformation state (Raphael API) is important for the rotational issue. While, for translating the element on drag requires absolute translation, which neglects the rotational state of the element while translating the element.

//EDIT NOTE

Drag bounding is worked on and updated. However, there remains an issue with incorporating the difference between mouse position and image center.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply NRC!  However, when you trimmed down the code, you removed the blue boundary.  I have been able to achieve what you have posted, but my issue is being able to drag and drop a rotated  element within a specified boundary.If you could give it another look and try to solve that issue then that might help!  Thanks again!

Comment: Pls check the updated fiddle state for a better version of the solution, which includes the bounding issue too. However, I am fine tuning it now to get the last bit of issues fixed for difference in mouse (x,y) and image center! Hope to update the answer soon.

Comment: Sorry, will try to fix this up later and update once I get home. Its too late now.  :)

Comment: Ok, that's fine!  I'll be working on this project for a while anyways.  Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with your rotation and drag problem, you need to store the rotation and apply it after you have moved the object.

```
elementClockwise.node.onclick = function()
{
    html5.animate({'transform': html5.transform() +'r90'}, 100, onAnimComplete);
}

elementCounterClockwise.node.onclick = function()
{
    html5.animate({'transform': html5.transform() +'r-90'}, 100, onAnimComplete);

}

function onAnimComplete(){
    default_transform = html5.transform();
}
```

At present I can't get the boundary to work, but will have a try later.

http://jsfiddle.net/n3Sn5/2/

Comment: Yeah I already have a version of it working already with the drag and rotate: [http://jsfiddle.net/S2s3T/](http://jsfiddle.net/S2s3T/)
The boundary is what is causing me all the trouble.  Thanks for trying though!  Let me know if you can get anything to work!